# Does heroic trigger when the creature is in a graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have an [Agent of the Fates](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Agent%20of%20the%20Fates) in my graveyard. I return it to my hand with [Disentomb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Disentomb).

Does my opponent have to sacrifice a creature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The Heroic ability only works if the creature you target is a permanent on the battlefield. *Most* abilities only work from the battlefield. From rule [112.6](http://magiccards.info/rule/112-abilities.html#rule-112-6):

> **112.6.** Abilities of an instant or sorcery spell usually function only while that object is on the stack. **Abilities of all other objects usually function only while that object is on the battlefield.** The exceptions are as follows:

There's a few exceptions, but the ones regarding activated or triggered abilities are ***i*** and ***j***. They're quoted in full below. The basic gist of these exceptions, and rule 112.6, is that no activated or triggered abilities work outside the battlefield — *unless* it involves a cost or trigger condition that *can't* work on the battlefield, in which case it works wherever it *can* work.

A good example of these exceptions (specifically exception ***i***) is *Scavenge* or *Bloodrush*. The former requires you to exile the card from your graveyard, and the latter requires you to discard it (and cards can only be discarded from your hand, nowhere else). Since those costs can only be paid somewhere outside the battlefield, *Scavenge* works inside your graveyard, and *Bloodrush* works inside your hand. (But that's the only places they work, since their costs can't be paid anywhere else.)

Since *Heroic* works just fine on the battlefield, though, it isn't covered by these exceptions (specifically the one regarding triggered abilities, exception ***j***) and doesn't get to work elsewhere too.

> **112.6i** An objects activated ability that has a cost that can't be paid while the object is on the battlefield functions from any zone in which its cost can be paid.
>
> **112.6j** A trigger condition that can't trigger from the battlefield functions in all zones it can trigger from. Other trigger conditions of the same triggered ability may function in different zones.
>
> *Example: Absolver Thrull has the ability "When Absolver Thrull enters the battlefield or the creature it haunts dies, destroy target enchantment." The first trigger condition functions from the battlefield and the second trigger condition functions from the exile zone. (See rule 702.54, "Haunt.")*

Comment: I think the golden rule of magic is more relevant here. ***101.1.** Whenever a card's text directly contradicts these rules, the card takes precedence.* Some cards specifically say you can activate the ability only from a specific zone (usually the graveyard), and so their rule takes precedence.

Comment: @Rainbolt The explanation I've provided is what got me understanding it when I was new. 101.1 doesn't make sense here, because the card doesn't contradict the rules - it doesn't have anything saying "this works in the graveyard" or "this works in your hand". Without 112.6 and its exceptions, some abilities just appear like some idiot wrote an ability that can't possibly work.

Comment: @Rainbolt, Jonathan Hobbs's assessment of why 101.1 doesn't apply is completely correct.

Comment: Both are valid. 112.6 is the rule, and 101.1 is applicable. 112.6i and 112.6j seem to be redundant corollaries of 101.1

Comment: @LuisMasuelli Not really. If "Exile this card from your graveyard:" is the cost, that doesn't actually *state* that you can pay this effect while the card is in the graveyard, any more than you can tap a mana elf while it's in the graveyard. 112.6 solves this problem.
Otherwise it would be argued that Elder of Laurels says you can pay mana to pump your creatures, and thus by 101.1, you can do that anywhere (after all, the card doesn't state that this is only true for cards on the battlefield, and if card "always beats the rules"...)

Comment: What @deworde said is precisely it. Pretty sure 101.1 is more applicable as the foundation of cards like [Platinum Angel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Platinum%20Angel).

Comment: @LuisMasuelli Note that Common Sense would also do the job, but the Judge program stopped using Common Sense long ago, after the realisation that a) two people can have legitimately conflicting views of what is sensible, and b) some players (who am I kidding, *most* players) would claim to speak like Yoda if it bought them an incremental advantage.

Comment: As evidence I present various questions genuinely asked about Worst Fears:  "Can I force my opponent to concede?" "Can I force my opponent to attack himself with his creatures?"  "Can I force my opponent to tear up his own cards with Blacker Lotus if he doesn't concede?" "Can I force my opponent to let me take cards from his deck?" "Can I force my opponent to take his top off if he doesn't concede?" "Can I force my opponent to rob a bank if he doesn't concede?" "Can I force my opponent to give me his wallet?" "Can I force my opponent to not concede so that he has to tear up his cards?"

Comment: The logic approached by those saying 101.1 is applicable when it isn't is invariably "X doesn't work in this situation by the rules, X should work in this situation, therefore X must override the rules, therefore X works in this situation", but the premise that X should work in this situation is entirely invented. A card only overrides the rules when it says something that directly contradicts a rule. (e.g. "You cannot lose.") There's nothing of the kind here.

Comment: I actually agree with @Ikegami here (a rare occasion). I wish to retract my comment about rule 101.1 being more relevant. However, I still have a problem with 112.6i. It only applies if the cost can't be paid. Consider an ability like *"2B: Return this card from the graveyard to your hand."* I can definitely pay the cost of 2B while the creature is on the battlefield, and yet this ability *still* only functions from the graveyard. There must be another rule that applies here.

Comment: Does such an ability actually exist? If you know of an example, I'll gladly look into it and update my answer. I'm only aware of abilities like _Flashback,_ where part of their ruling is "You may cast this from your graveyard." (Kapow, 101.1.)

Comment: Ashen Ghoul, Chronosavant, etc. @Rainbolt The answer is 112.6*k*, which handles exactly this situation.

Comment: @Jonathan Hobbs, Flashback's allows casting from the graveyard (a 101.1 situation), but what allows Flashback itself to operate in the graveyard? It's not actually covered by any of the 112.6 exceptions! Oddly, it's only allowed by the definition of Flashback. ("It represents two static abilities: one that functions while the card is in a player’s graveyard and another that functions while the card is on the stack.") "You may cast this from your graveyard" wouldn't actually work on a card.